# AdMob Banner Unit Not Displaying Ads (Capacitor)?

Tags: admob, capacitor

I'm trying to get my ad unit to show ads, but so far it just shows a blank space where the ads should be.

I've been able to display test banner ads without issue, but when I switch the ad ID to my actual ad it doesn't show.

The ad unit and app were created a few days ago, so I should be over the wait period.

I've used the Mediation Test Suite (Android) to debug, and this is what I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/55l72.png (image is huge so I'll just link it).

I'm using Capacitor to build my app using web code, along with the capacitor-admob NPM package to display AdMob ads.

Nothing unusual is jumping out in Logcat (though it's possible I missed something as there is a lot of information in there), and my JavaScript console for the WebView (in chrome://inspect) is displaying that the ad is showing:

[image]

I've checked my AdMob settings and verified my account is in good standing.

I'm pretty stumped where to go from here.

Any insight on the situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello sir, did you fix this issue ?

Comment: I believe the issue resolved itself after waiting for AdMob.